# unable to run docker flask image -pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, docker, flask, pymongo

I have built a docker image for a flask app I have with some html templates and after running my image I go to `localhost:5000`which takes me to the start page in my flask app . I press a register button to register a user using a flask endpoint but I get

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Before going to localhost I run my mongodb image with `sudo docker start mongodb`and the connection seems to hit this error whenever I have to search something in my monogdb database for the endpoint . Do I need a docker-compose.yml to connect and I cannot connect without one ?

This is how I connect to mongodb using pymongo

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['MovieFlixDB']

users = db['Users']
movies = db['Movies']
```

How I run my flask app :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I would appreciate your help . Thank you in advance

Comment: @michalk could you provide an example ?

Comment: did you publish 27017 port in your compose?

Answer (score 7):

To connect containers to each other you should use networks.

1. First you create a network

```
docker network create my-network
```

2. Run mongodb specyfing the network.

```
docker container run -d --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 --network my-network mongodb:latest
```

3. Modify your app to connect to `mongodb` as host instead of localhost. Containers that are connected to a common network can talk to each other by using their names (DNS names) that can be automatically resolved to container IPs.

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://mongodb:27017/')
```

You could also think about providing such deatils (db host, user, password) through environment variables and read them in your app.

4. Rebuild image with your app and run it

```
docker container run --name flask-app -d --network my-network my-flaskapp-image
```

You can read more about container networking in docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need a docker-compose.yml to connect and I cannot connect without
> one ?

If you use docker-compose, it will be easier and don't have to use too many commands to deploy. Look at [this example](https://github.com/danionescu0/docker-flask-mongodb-example#random-service) (there are too many however you can refer random service).

Steps -

1. Build your docker-componse file [I have modified the one in the example of random service, removing rest] e.g.

```
version: '3.3'
  
services:
    web-random:
        build:
            context: .
            args:
                requirements: ./flask-mongodb-example/requirements.txt
        image: web-random-image
        ports:
            - "800:5000"
        entrypoint: python ./flask-mongodb-example/random_demo.py
        depends_on:
            - mongo

    mongo:
        image: mongo:4.2-bionic
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
```

2. Refer [this example](https://github.com/danionescu0/docker-flask-mongodb-example/blob/master/python/random_demo.py) to update your mongo URL in your python code
3. Now, use the following command to compose and bring up the containers

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

4. Now, either browse your URL with browser or use the curl command

Comment: So I can create a file like this without testing my flask image and worrying if it will work alone with mongodb running ?

Comment: You will still need to change the MongoDB connection URL to match the Compose service name `mongo:27017`; each container is still its own `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a very simple solution, the mongo host url should be

```
mongodb://mongodb:27017
```

Because it is a service.
Just that.